# Verbose logging: howto save disk?

Tags: logs, pty

### Situation

I'm running a program on Linux, which produces a **lot of verbose logs** to `stdout`.

The program itself is put into background by using `systemd.service` facilities.

Until now, I have configured the program to store only the major loglevels to disk (to be read with `syslog` or `journalctl`), and keep printing the minor, verbose logs to `stdout`.

There was a pretty solid app called [reredirect](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect) which could reattach me to the verbose-logging pty.

So, whenever some misbehaviour happened in the program, I could reattach myself to this pty, and investigate the verbose logs on what is going on.

### Problem

I've changed the architecture to *aarch64* and reredirect is not seem available on this platform.

### Possible solutions

1. Save all the verbose logs to disk and examine them just as usual: NOK, as verbose log is really huge, will stress the storage, or if I mount it into `tmpfs`, it might rotate (as it's huge), and I'll lose earlier, more important major logs.
2. Starting it in pseudo-tty: wastes resources, thus I have no clue on the feasibility of a systemd.service usage along with screen or tmux.

Most of the time, I need only the major logs. I'm checking it once per week, or bi-weekly.

But when a strange behaviour happens, I need to deepdive right into the verbose logs. Restarting the application is not an option because I'd lose the misbehavior, so as the logs.

So, how can I reattach my current pty to a custom application's default one on aarch64?

Comment: Maybe one of these tools for "size-capped, automatically rotated, log file sets" https://superuser.com/a/291397

Answer (score 0):

You can send verbose logs from the program to a file and inject them from the file into syslog. Rotate this file frequently. From syslog filter log messages with different priorities into different files and rotate these files according to your preferences.

Comment: For this I need to have a tmpfs for the output, a daemon which handles the rotating and injections from this file to syslog. Also a serious synchronization might be needed, as the program writes to the file frequently (@ms level), and then the daemon wants to read it fast, to not lose any higher level errors. How can I handle this in practical way?